# Is there a way to make a bean thread-scope?

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I want an object to be bound to the current thread in one Spring bean that is singleton scope. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean a `ThreadLocal` ?

Comment: Your question title and question body do not match.  You want a thread scoped bean, or a singleton bean to hold a thread scoped object?

Comment: @Affe - I think he is looking to do the second.

Comment: Or a threadlocal bean injected in a singleton bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe implementing an aspect with Spring's [ThreadLocalTargetSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/target/ThreadLocalTargetSource.html). It is explained very well in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-ts-threadlocal):

> ThreadLocal target sources are useful if you need an object to be
>   created for each incoming request (per thread that is). The concept of
>   a ThreadLocal provide a JDK-wide facility to transparently store
>   resource alongside a thread. Setting up a ThreadLocalTargetSource is
>   pretty much the same as was explained for the other types of target
>   source:

```
<bean id="threadlocalTargetSource" class="org.springframework.aop.target.ThreadLocalTargetSource">
  <property name="targetBeanName" value="businessObjectTarget"/>
</bean>
```